# Copy specific file to a specific server from a list of servers

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I want to copy a specific file from localhost to a specific remote 
server.
Example:

file1 ---- server1

file2 ---- server2

file3 ---- server3

Have tried the below solutions but its iterating through all the server and copying the file to all the servers.

deploy.yaml

```
---
- hosts: dev
  gather_facts: True
  vars:
   version: 1.0.0

  tasks:

  - name: "copying the service files to remote hosts"
    copy:
      src: ./abc/{{ item.service }}/{{ item.build }}-{{ version }}.zip
      dest: ~/{{ item.build }}-{{ version }}.zip
      force: yes
    delegate_to: "{{ item.service }}"
    with_items:
       - { service: "abc", build: "abc-service" }
       - { service: "bcd" , build: "bcd-service" }
       - { service: "mvn" , build: "mvn-service" }
       - { service: "ansible" , build: "ans-service" }
```

inventory

```
[dev]
abc ansible_ssh_host=12.xx.xx.6 ansible_user=dev
bcd ansible_ssh_host=12.xx.xx.7 ansible_user=dev
mvn ansible_ssh_host=12.xx.xx.3 ansible_user=dev
ansible ansible_ssh_host=12.xx.xx.8 ansible_user=dev
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in many ways i guess. one approach is to add variables `service` and `build` in the inventory, inventory would look like:

```
[dev]
abc ansible_ssh_host=12.xx.xx.6 ansible_user=dev service=abcbuild=abc
bcd ansible_ssh_host=12.xx.xx.7 ansible_user=dev service=bcd build=bcd
mvn ansible_ssh_host=12.xx.xx.3 ansible_user=dev service=mvn build=mvn
ansible ansible_ssh_host=12.xx.xx.8 ansible_user=dev service=ansible build=ans
```

Or you could have a list variable in your play to contain this information, up to you where/how to store it.

and your task would not need the `with_items` clause anymore:

```
  - name: "copying the service files to remote hosts"
    copy:
      src: ./abc/{{ service }}/{{ build }}-{{ version }}.zip
      dest: ~/{{ build }}-{{ version }}.zip
      force: yes
    delegate_to: "{{ service }}"
```

hope it helps